# Same bot app on multiple Facebook pages webhooks issue

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

my bot app is running on more Facebook pages, the issue is that if the app gets uninstalled from the settings of a single page, all webhooks are deleted also from other pages and so gets the bot. Has anyone experienced and solved this issue without the need of having one app per page?

Comment: That should not happen; using the same app to serve multiple pages is a common and supported use case. // Please describe the exact steps that were undertaken to uninstall the app from the page, maybe that was handled incorrectly?

Comment: What have been done was going to the fanpage Settings -> Messenger Platform and uninstall the bot app. However inside Messenger settings of the bot app in developers portal I saw all the pages that were subscribed to webhooks were disappeared and not only the one from which I uninstalled the app.

Comment: If you can reproduce that reliably, then you should file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes I can, I'll open the bug. Thanks